# How to delay a nested iteration when the innermost loop waits for response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, jquery-callback

Here's an overview of my problem statement:

I am working on trying to generate the solution for an online multiple choice questionnaire form. The idea is to write a javascript function that iterates through all the questions and finds out the right answers.

For the sake of simplicity, I shall attempt only one question, uniquely identified by the `levelNo` and `questionNo` variables, select an option, submit the `form` through javascript, thereby submitting a response for the one selected question and skipping all the other questions.

The `result` from the form submit is the number of correct responses. So, if the `result` from the form submit is a `"1"`, then the option selected was right, else wrong. I keep iterating over the options for each question, till I find the right answer.

**The Typical Synchronicity Problem**

Now, the problem is that the form submit takes considerable time and my javascript code carries on without waiting for the request to complete and the response to come back. I wish to delay the iteration, until the response loads.

```
function solve(){
    var options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    for(var levelNo = 1; levelNo<=5; levelNo++){
        for(var questionNo = 1; questionNo <=10; questionNo++){
            var solved = false;
            for(var i=0; i<4 && !solved; i++){
                var questionId = levelNo+'_'+questionNo; 

                $.ajax({
                    method:"POST", 
                    url: "get_scores.php",
                    data : questionId+'='+options[i]
                }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var sectionScore = $(data).text().trim();               
                    if(sectionScore == "1"){
                        solved = true;
                        console.log(questionNo+"->"+options[i]);    
                    }   
                });                 
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

As one can see, I have solved the problem for one request, by using the `jQuery.done()` for the `AJAX` call. However, I am not able to solve this for the iteration.

I understand that the design of my approach is totally incorrect in the sense of synchrony, as I am waiting for the response each time before proceeding with my iteration. I could solve the problem using sequential `XMLHttpRequest` and setting `async` to false in jQuery AJAX.

But I wanted to explore this approach in the hope/expectation of learning more about callbacks/closures, as my research has seen many posts talking about callbacks as a potential solution to this kind of problems.

So, I'd like to know, out of academic interest, if the above problem can be solved using Asynchronous requests and callbacks, in particular. If so, how? If not, why isn't the concept of a callback applicable in this sceanrio? Is there any other javascript principle that could be used?

**TL;DR** : I wish to delay a nested iteration, until the JSON response from a website loads. Can callbacks help ?

Comment: You're sending 250 ajax calls simultaneously? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Stryner: I wish to delay the iteration, until the response loads.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. But note that `for(var x = ...` is very bad practice in Javascript, since Javascript does not have block scope, and `for` does not start a new scope for your variables. You should declare all your variables immediately at the beginning of function body.

Comment: @gamliela Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you are trying to "hack" the questionnaire to get the right questions by calling that POST method with all the possible combinations?

Comment: @epuigvros: Exactly...!!! But in order to proceed with each option in each iteration, I need to wait until the response returns from the website. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Then you cannot have this inside a "for" loop because it's synchronous, you should have a kind of queue system where you make the requests one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, note however that I am checking always all the answers. A better approach should avoid calling again for the same question if you already have the right answer.

```
var options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

var answers = [];
var solutions = {};
var requestScore = function(questionId,optionSelected){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST", 
        url: "get_scores.php",
        data : questionId+'='+optionSelected
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var sectionScore = $(data).text().trim();               
        if(sectionScore == "1"){
            solutions[questionId] = optionSelected;
        }
        if ( answers.length > 0 ){
            requestScore.apply( this, answers.shift() );
        }else console.log( solutions ); //your solutions
    });
};

for(var levelNo = 1; levelNo<=5; levelNo++){
    for(var questionNo = 1; questionNo <=10; questionNo++){
        for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
            var questionId = levelNo+'_'+questionNo; 
            answers.push( [questionId,optionSelected] );//wherever optionSelected comes from               
        }           
    }
}

requestScore.apply( this, answers.shift() );
```

Comment: Awesome.. This was the kind of solution approach I was looking for. Also, it is a highly enlightening post for me. And to avoid calling after we have the right solution, we could simply set `solved` to true when the score is 1, thereby branching out based on the `!solved` criteria in the innermost for.

Comment: I am not using the solved variable in my approach, I just removed it from the for since was there when I copied it.

Comment: To avoid calling again for the same question, you should check if the answers array contains the question that you already solved and remove it before continuing with the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution and this seems to be working for me. However, I am making recursive calls to re-attempt for each question and thereby achieving synchrony of the data.

```
var options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var answers = [];
var solutions = [];

function attempt(levelNo, questionId, optionSelected){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST", 
        url: "get_scores.php",
        data : questionId+'='+optionSelected,           
        success : function (data){
            var sectionScore = $(data).text().trim();    
            if(sectionScore == "1"){
                solutions[questionId] = optionSelected;             
                answers.push( [questionId, optionSelected] );              
                console.log(solutions);  
            } else{
                // Keep trying with the next option.        
                var nextOption = options[options.indexOf(optionSelected)+1];
                attempt(levelNo, questionId, nextOption);                       
            }           
        }
    });
};

function solve(){
    for(var levelNo = 1; levelNo<=1; levelNo++){
        for(var questionNo = 1; questionNo <=4; questionNo++){
            var questionId = levelNo+"_"+questionNo; 
            attempt(levelNo, questionId, options[0]); // start with first option
        }
    }
}
solve();
```